# Git push gets stuck

Tags: git, push, trace

Recently I formatted my computer and had to install Git again. I have successfully cloned a repo from GitHub, made changes, staged, added, and committed the changes.
However, whenever I tried to push the changes it just gets stuck. Here's the trace I got from `GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master`:

> 01:12:03.816452 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable
> dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin 01:12:03.816452 git.c:455
> trace: built-in: git push origin main 01:12:03.824024
> run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git
> remote-https origin https://github.com/PragatiJ55/Portfolio.git
> 01:12:03.839258 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable
> dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core 01:12:03.839258
> git.c:744               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin
> https://github.com/PragatiJ55/Portfolio.git 01:12:03.839258
> run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin
> https://github.com/PragatiJ55/Portfolio.git 01:12:03.859211
> exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core 01:12:04.464180 run-command.c:667
> trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager-core get' 01:12:04.534237
> exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core 01:12:04.544243 git.c:744
> trace: exec: git-credential-manager-core get 01:12:04.544243
> run-command.c:667       trace: run_command:
> git-credential-manager-core get

I tried to set the ssh key however it still gives the same error.

Comment: @matt It does. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to add your username and email to git config with:

```
git config --global user.name "Bob"
git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
```

Comment: I already did that. Matt's comment helped.